# (ngModelChange) delete last symbol (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 inputs where I enter value and concat it into new one

Here is code from HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("FirstName")}}</label>
                    <input #firstNameInput="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" (ngModelChange)="onNameChange()"  [(ngModel)]="landlord.firstName"  required maxlength="32">
                    <validation-messages [formCtrl]="firstNameInput"></validation-messages>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("LastName")}}</label>
                    <input #lastNameInput="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" (ngModelChange)="onNameChange()" [(ngModel)]="landlord.lastName"  required maxlength="32">
                    <validation-messages [formCtrl]="lastNameInput"></validation-messages>
                </div>
```

And concat value I show in this field

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("OrganizationName")}}</label>
                    <input #organizationName="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" name="organizationName" [(ngModel)]="landlord.organizationName" required maxlength="500">
                    <validation-messages [formCtrl]="organizationName"></validation-messages>
                </div>
```

Here is code from ts file

```
onNameChange() {
    this.landlord.organizationName = `${
        this.landlord.firstName ? this.landlord.firstName : ''
    } ${this.landlord.lastName ? this.landlord.lastName : ''}`;
}
```

My problem, that last character is deleted from firstName or lastName

How I can fux this stuff?

Comment: Please reproduce the issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ngModelChange` event is firing before the model is actually updated, so with the current value **at the time the event is fired**, prior to the change. Likely to do [with the ordering of](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11234) `(ngModelChange)` and `[(ngModel)]` in your template.

Change your event to fire on `(input)` and it will get the most recent value.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{l("FirstName")}}</label>
    <input #firstNameInput="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" (input)="onNameChange($event)"  [(ngModel)]="landlord.firstName"  required maxlength="32">
</div>
```

**OR**

Change the order of your attributes in your template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{l("FirstName")}}</label>
    <input #firstNameInput="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="landlord.firstName" (ngModelChange)="onNameChange()"   required maxlength="32">
</div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p7ecgh

Comment: That's helps. Thanks